# Make Sonarqube 6.7.5 Community version comment on pull requests

Tags: sonarqube, pull-request, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-ops

I'm trying to update Sonarqube usage to the latest LTS *Community* version, which at present is version 6.7.5.  Prior to the upgrade I have been using sonarqube 5.4 and the [Github plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin), and with these when we make Github pull requests the Sonarqube analysis runs in "preview" scan mode and makes comments on the pull request for any issues the scan finds.  This setup is largely following [this pattern](http://techtalkbook.com/sonarqube-git-analysis/).

However, with the upgrade to 6.7.5 this same flow is no longer working.  The Github plugin

> "is deprecated, and its functionality more than replaced by the
>   Developer Edition."

I understand that the Developer version of Sonarqube has pull request commenting built-in, but I have a strong preference to continue using the Community version due to the cost differences.  Essentially, something that was once free and part of the open source version seems to have been removed or broken in the latest free and open source version because a similar paid option now exists.  So I am trying to find a way to preserve the previous Community version usage with the latest Community Sonarqube version.  6.7.5 Community version runs the Github plugin (even though it the plugin is deprecated), but so far I have been unable to get things to make comments on the Github pull requests.

**Is there a combination of parameters/plugins that will allow my 6.7.5 Community version of Sonarqube to analyze and make comments on a Github pull request?**

These may be relevant:

- https://community.sonarsource.com/t/after-upgrade-to-sq-6-7-5-target-sonar-issues-report-issues-report-light-html-is-not-produced/1921
- https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9770
- https://community.sonarsource.com/t/preview-mode-ignored/1234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in my case the issue was that after upgrading the rule sets changed, so the rules I initially thought were being used with 6.7.5 were not in fact being applied.  This gave the impression that Sonarqube was not commenting on the pull request and led to my question.  But after enabling the rules appropriately I was able to see it comment on GitHub pull requests as expected.  So this appears to be a case of user error!